# Implement Lazy Loading of Hierarchical StackLayout in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**TL;DR: I want to:**

1. Save some c# object in every StackLayout
2. Use information from this object to render another StackLayouts if user wants it.

**Details:**

I want to display all Html DOM Tree of Objects of some website as a list.

I'm using Html Agility Pack to manage downloaded html. It creates a List of HtmlNode objects that has some HtmlNodes as children, that has some HtmlNodes as children etc. (just like in HTML DOM).

This is what I currently have:

```
private StackLayout GenerateTreeOfHtmlObjects(HtmlNode htmlNode, int padding)
    {
        StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
        stackLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
        foreach (var childNode in htmlNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (childNode.Name != "#text")
            {
                Button showMoreButton = new Button { Text = ">", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, };

                stackLayout.Children.Add(
                    new StackLayout
                    {
                        Children = {
                            showMoreButton,
                            new Label { Text = childNode.Name, FontSize=20 },
                            new Label { Text = new string(childNode.InnerText.Trim().ToCharArray().Take(30).ToArray()), FontSize=15 },
                            new Button { Text = "Zaznacz" },
                            GenerateTreeOfHtmlObjects(childNode, padding+10) //RECURSION, CALL THIS FUNCTION AGAIN AS LONG AS THERE ARE SOME CHILDREN
                        },

                        Padding = new Thickness(padding, 0, 0, 10)
                    }
                );
            }
        }
        return stackLayout;
    }
```

As you see, I'm creating StackLayout for every HtmlNode and add another StackLayouts for their children. It works more or less as I wanted, but the problem is **it takes too much memory and takes very long to load**.

So I want to **load children of some HtmlNode only if user click on their parent**. I will load only those HtmlNodes that are on the top of the tree and successively load their children if they were needed.

To do this, **I need to store somewhere in every StackLayout some information about what to load if user click on it**. Every currently loaded StackLayout has to have HtmlNode class assigned that will allow me to load children of HtmlNode (every HtmlNode has ChildNodes variable and I will take information from there)

Comment: You can create a custom stacklayout with some attributes(e.g classname) of your own, and then use the values of your attributes to determine which stacklayout it is.

Comment: Use MVVM pattern. Then, you'll have ViewModel that holds all the information about the view. see:https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

Answer (score 3):

Use MVVM pattern. Then, you'll have ViewModel that holds all the information about the view. see:https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

```
        //// MODEL            
        public class HtmlNode
        {
          public List<HtmlNode> Children{get; set;}
        }

        //// VIEW-MODEL
        public class HtmlTreeViewModel
        {
          public HtmlNode RootNode {get; set;}

          public List<HtmlNode> TreeItems{get; set;}
          ICommand ItemClickedCommand;
          public HtmlTreeViewModel()
          {
           // Get Initial Items
           TreeItems = GenerateTreeOfHtmlObjects(RootNode);
           ItemClickedCommand = new Command(ItemClickCommadFunc);
          }

          private List<HtmlNode> ItemClickCommadFunc(object itemClicked)
          {
              // Fill Children for specific node
              HtmlNode node =(itemClicked as HtmlNode);
              node.Children = GenerateTreeOfHtmlObjects(node);
          }

        }


        //// VIEW
    //This is the datatemplate for each item (you can add name and other stuff)
    //should be defined in resources
    <DataTemplate x:key="NodeTemplate">
       <StackLayout ItemSource="{Binding Children}">
       </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>

    //this is the StackLayout that represent the whole tree
    <StackLayout ItemsSource="{Binding RootItem.Children}" ItemTemplate=" StaticResource NodeTemplate}"/>
```

This is just to give you an idea, you'll have to connect the dots by yourself. Don't forget to assign BindingContext to the StackPanel and raise PropertyChanged when necessary.